# Best way to dynamically create an if statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

I'm writing an AdWords script that will be used within the agency and requires users to change a variable which is an array containing certain things that need to be excluded, so I need to create an if statement that excludes all of these.

I can't know beforehand how many elements will actually be in the array, so I've currently created this:

```
  var exclusions = ["a", "b", "c"];

  var exclusionInput = "if (url.indexOf('";

  for (var i = 0; i < exclusions.length; i++) {
    if (exclusions.length - i == 1) {
      var exclusion = exclusions[i];
      var exclusionString = exclusion.toString();
      exclusionInput = exclusionInput + exclusionString + "') != -1)  {toExclude.push(url); Logger.log(url) }";
    } else {
      var exclusion = exclusions[i];
      var exclusionString = exclusion.toString();
      exclusionInput = exclusionInput + exclusionString + "') != -1 || url.indexOf('";
    }   
  }
```

The problem is that this only works if I later do eval:

```
eval(exclusionInput);
```

(at least as far as I can see, it doesn't work if I just add in exclusionInput on it's own).

This code works perfectly so far, but in my searches on how to do do this everyone kept saying that I should try to never use eval if possible. The main concern is security, which isn't really an issue here as it's all within the Google Ads shell and will only be used by employees of my agency, but I was still wondering if there's a better way to achieve this that doesn't require eval.

Comment: uh, what about just inverting it as something like `exclusions.includes(url)` instead of `url.indexOf(exclusions[0])` and so on?

Comment: I don't realy understand what you need to do, but: have you considered using a factory of functions, i.e a function that returns a function. Can you add more code in your question?

Comment: Do you want to exclude certain urls depending if the exclusion item is in the url?

Comment: @enxaneta OP is trying to literally build an `if` statement as a string. So with the given example, the condition would look like `if (url.indexOf("a") != -1 || url.indexOf("b") != -1 || url.indexOf("c") != -1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to create a IF statement programmatically. See this:

```js
var exclusions = ['a', 'a', 'a'];
var exclusions2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var url = 'http://url-to-be-excluded.com';

function shouldIExclude(exclusions, url) {
  return exclusions.map(exclusion => url.includes(exclusion)).some(b => b);  
}

console.log(shouldIExclude(exclusions, url));
console.log(shouldIExclude(exclusions2, url));
```

Comment: Instead of `reduce`, it's even simpler to say `.some(Boolean)` to check if any value is true. It's even shorter with an identity function `.some(x=>x)`

Comment: awesome, thanks! as you can probably tell i'm still quite new to javascript so didn't know either of these existed, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you can use a function to build a function to evaluate your statement. So the steps on this one are:

1. Declare the url as variable
2. Build your return statement (aka your ifs)
3. Create the function and run it

This approach generally is a safer alternative to JS's eval as everything is declared as a variable.

Hope this helps.

```js
const exclusions = ['a', 'a', 'a'];
const exclusions2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const url = 'http://url-to-be-excluded.com';

const myEval = (array, url) => {

    let functionString = `const url = '${url}'; return (`;

    array.forEach((item) => functionString += `(url.indexOf('${item}') !== -1) || `);

    functionString += `false)`;
    
    // Create and run the function to evaluate
    
    return new Function(functionString)();
};

console.log(myEval(exclusions, url));
console.log(myEval(exclusions2, url));
```